# Strange small variation of memory bandwidth (but not CPU perf) on frequency-locked Cortex A15 device

Tags: linux, performance, memory, benchmarking

I need an ARM platform with stable performance characteristics for precise benchmarking. Currently I'm working with Exynos 5422 Cortex A15/A7 device.

I've got less than 0.1% short-term (in 10 second range) performance variation by disabling all kinds of frequency scaling features in the Linux kernel, using a separate CPU core for my task and moving IRQs and kernel workqueues out of that core.

Unfortunately, the memory bandwidth seems to be reduced by ~2% during random intervals of several minutes as if it has two states and switches between then. I'm able to get less than 0.1% short-term variation, so this is not caused by measurement error. Since the reduction of is small it's unlikely that it's caused by memory frequency changes or something like that. High precision measurements show that the bandwidth reduction is extremely uniform and is not caused by increased frequency of some activity spikes. For example, I can see bandwidth changes caused by various interrupts on other cores, the cause is something else. Temperature changes also don't have effect on this.

Does anyone have any ideas what could cause this random long-term memory bandwidth reduction?

Comment: Could DMA be competing for memory bandwidth?  And just to be clear, are you saying you've ruled out something stealing CPU cycles from the core your code is running on, so it's just memory bandwidth?  (e.g. by changing your microbenchmark to only use ALU instructions with no memory access other than code fetch).  Do you have perf counters that can tell whether you're getting a TLB miss (e.g. from an invalidation for some reason), or whether cache misses increase (which might indicate that prefetch had a hiccup)?

Comment: Yes, I've ruled out all couses within the CPU itself. TLB misses are the same. The ratio of L2 miss/total requests is higher when the benchmark is slower - which is what would be expected if available bandwidth is reduced and prefetch completes fewer pages until a cache miss.

Answer (score 1):

Memory behavior is extremely complex(*). One approach is to actually perform many run, get their metrix and apply your statistics knowledge to refine the results. You may get as stable as you can and double check that, the problem is the next run, you may very well get something different for an unknown reason and will not even see it, if you do not check.

They are specialized benchmarking tools that will do just this and compute automatically relevant statistics and help you determine how accurate your benchmark was. An example  in Java would be JMH. Of course in your environment this would be different, except if you can trigger your computation by network.

It can be rewarding to find the cause to your bandwidth issue, and I hope you'll find it. But for me there are benefits with being able to live with such issue and get the most out of it.

(*) What you need inside the memory can be in L1, L2 or L3 cache. Or you may have to fetch it from memory. Depending of the memory design and what was requested before, the access to that data can again vary greatly.

The harwdware itself use the memory for the display and various other devices. The memory itself can keep the information live for only a very short time and so the memory controller will refresh the content of the memory, affecting its bandwidth and reactivity. (That also explain what the content is lost in case of power loss: not refreshed in time). The system itself may decide to redistribute the memory accross programs, defragment it, use for some background task...

Comment: The OP is writing a specialized memory-benchmark tool, presumably one with more accuracy than you could achieve in a managed language like Java.  DRAM refresh is a good suggestion, though.

Comment: I agree java is really not the best for consistancy due to all intermediate layers. But it only add on top of the existing problems. I did found the statistical approach of JMH interresting as you actually measure the dicrepency while running the benchmark and can then issue a score with a confidence factor. If you do a single measurement, or don't use that information you'll never know if there was a fluctuation. It could work finally on the OP machine and fail on the next machine and nobody would ever know.

Comment: I don't suggest JVM or java for the benchmark, I just suggest to make a statistical analysis of the results part of the benchmark...